# Force redirect after Jquery AJAX Call from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, http-redirect

I have a custom framework and I detect if a request is an **ajax** in my **Request** file. In my basecontroller I check if user is logged in:

```
If user is not logged in:
  1. if request is ajax - force JS redirect from PHP (unable to do)
  2. if request is not ajax - PHP redirect (header, works)
```

I cant get number **1** to work.

Here is my redirect code:

```
//User::Redirect
public function redirect($url = SITE_URL, $isAjax = false) {
    if ($isAjax === true) {
        //its ajax call, echo js redirect
        echo '<script>window.location = ' . $url . ';</script>';
    } else {
        header("Location: {$url}");
    }
    exit;
}
```

Code for login check:

```
//Basecontroller::__construct
if ( ! $this->user->isLoggedIn()) {
   //redirect to login page
   $this->user->redirect('/login', $request->ajax()); 
   exit;
}
```

But instead of redirecting on **ajax** calls it just outputs `<script>window.location = URL</script>`

**NOTE:**

I know i could add check on each of my AJAX call to do redirect from there but Im trying to avoid that and let my PHP script detect in base controller and redirect rather than me adding check to all of my AJAX calls (alot).

Comment: Just as a recommendation, I tend to pass all ajax calls through one generic function,  and this function handles the http redirection if one has been sent.

Comment: so you have one giant file that contains all of your ajax calls ?

Comment: no I have one small file, that contains a generic ajax function, with a couple of variations for differing purposes, but ultimately every request goes through the same function.

Comment: you mean a Javascript function that you use to call all ajax?

Comment: yes.  so all of my ajax calls in some way go through this function,  which handles various http responses including redirect.

Comment: I might need  to do that if I cant find a solution to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Javascript redirect needs script tags.  Try this:

```
public function redirect($url = SITE_URL, $isAjax = false) {
    if ($isAjax === true) {
        //its ajax call, echo js redirect
        echo '<script>window.location = ' . $url . ';</script>';
    } else {
        header("Location: {$url}");
    }
    exit;
}
```

In terms of handling this within your ajax,  assuming jQuery

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postParams,
        success: function(data)
        {
            //do something with success response
        },
        error : function(httpObj, txtStatus)
        {
            if(httpObj.status == 401)
            {//redirect to login
                var loginUrl = '/login';
                document.location.href = loginUrl;
            }
            else if(httpObj.status == ...)  //etc
            {//do something

            }
            else
            {
                alert("Ajax\n Error: " + txtStatus + "\n HTTP Status: " + httpObj.status);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might be missing  the surrounding html.  Take a look at the response from Nick above.

Comment: still nothing even with html

Comment: add this line `header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");`

Answer (score 1):

How is the client supposed to know that is javascript?

Try encasing it with script tags
i.e.

```
<html>
<script>
window.location = 'testpage.html'
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. If an ajax call finds the user is not logged in (eg: the user has left their browser open and their session has expired) the PHP will echo out the refresh code either as JS or a meta tag to the browser to force a refresh of the whole page.

```
$url = '/index.php';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
echo '</script>';
echo '<noscript>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
echo '</noscript>';
```